# Simple inner product question.

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there ever a case where ||x||$^2$ will not equal $<x,x>$? I don't understand why ||x||$^2$ is used sometimes.

Comment: I thought that $||x||$ is defined as $\sqrt{\langle x,x \rangle}$...

Comment: it is... so does that mean the two above are always equal?

Comment: Just square both sides from that definition...

Comment: @Shalop: While it is true that the inner-product $<,>$ gives rise to a norm, we may at times use a norm different from $ <x,x>^{1/2}$

Answer (score 3):

There are many contexts in which $\|x\|$ is defined to be a norm other than $\sqrt{\langle x,x \rangle}$.  For example, we might want to consider the $1$-norm, which would be defined by
$$
\|x\|_1 = |x_1| + \cdots + |x_n|
$$
and perhaps it would be more convenient to write $\|\cdot\|$ than $\|\cdot \|_1$.

---

On the other hand, it could just be a typesetting issue.  That is, it could simply be that the author finds $\|x\|^2$ easier to type than $\langle x,x \rangle$.  This is especially true when taking the norm of complicated expressions.  For example, it's much easier to read or write
$$
\|c_1 v_1 + \cdots + c_n v_n\|^2
$$
than it is to read or write
$$
\langle c_1 v_1 + \cdots + c_n v_n, c_1 v_1 + \cdots + c_n v_n\rangle
$$

Comment: I think it is just a convenience thing. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something wholly stupid.

Answer (score 0):

All inner product spaces $(X, <,>)$ have a naturally induced norm $||\cdot||: X \to \mathbb{R}$, given by $||x|| = \sqrt{<x, x>}$, so $(X,||\cdot||)$ is a normed space. So $||x||^2 = <x, x>$. There may be other norms defined on the space, but the usual norm we talk about is the induced norm, unless the author mentions something else.

Answer (score 0):

There are spaces where the norm is not generated by an inner-product. As an example, for $p \neq 2$, the norm $(\int f^p)^{1/p}$ is not given by ay inner-product $<f,f>$. This is a result of, I think, Holder's inequality. The key point here is, I think, that While it is true that the inner-product $<,>$ gives rise to a norm given by $||x||^2=<x,x>$, we may at times use a norm different from $ <x,x>^{1/2}$, as is the case of $L^p ; p \neq 2$.